# How to check a Radio button from the value of a table of mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, get

I have a table with the fields name and gender. I get the data and I try to display the information in the input fields, and it works on the input text Name, but i wonder if i can check the radio buttons depending of the data i get from the table?

```
<?php 
$sql="select * from empleo where id='$id';"; 

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));}

$cs=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($resul=mysqli_fetch_array($cs)){
            $name=$resul[0];
            $sexo=$resul[1];
            }
?>

Name: <input  type="text" value="<?php echo $name?>"/><br>

<label for="radio">Hombre</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio" value="men">

<label for="radio" > Mujer</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio" value="women">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your `$result[1]` is `W` for women and `M` for men (*change the code, if not*):

```
<label for="radio">Hombre</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio" value="men" <?php if($sexo=="M") echo "checked" ?>>

<label for="radio" > Mujer</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio2" value="women" <?php if($sexo=="W") echo "checked" ?>>
```

Read [Radio Button Input](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="sexo-men">Hombre</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="sexo-men" value="men" <?php $sexio === 'men' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> />

<label for="sexo-women">Mujer</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="sexo-women" value="women" <?php $sexio === 'women' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
```

And also `id` attribute of html is must unique on the page.

Comment: YUP THANKS FOR TELLING ME ABOUT THE ID. I TRIED YOUR CODE BUT DIDNT WORK :( IDK WHY ANY WAY I LOVE THIS FORUM I TRIED OTHERS CODES AND ONE WORKED THANK YOU!! FOR YOUR HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

Checking a checkbox in HTML is done with the `checked` attribute:

```
<input name="awesome" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

So we can setup a little function to help us output this:

```
function check_if($condition) {
    if ($condition) {
        echo 'checked="checked"';
    }
}
```

The problem with your script is that you only set up variables for your first record from your `empleo` table.
What you most likely want is to instead loop through all the records:

```
// Lets get all the records from result and as an associative array
$employees = mysqli_fetch_all($cs, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// this lets us use column names instead of indexes - much easier to read the code.
foreach($employees as $e) { ?>

    <label for="name">Name<label><input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $e['name']?>"/>

    <label for="gender">Hombre</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio" value="male" <?php check_if($e['gender'] === 'male') ?>>

    <label for="gender">Mujer</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio" value="female" <?php check_if($e['gender'] === 'female') ?>>

<?php } // end foreach ?>
```

I assumed the columns in your `empleo` table where `gender` and `name`.

You also should note that each `<input>` should have a `name` attribute and each `<label>` should have a `for`
attribute which matches the `name` of the input it labels.

Comment: also the correct english terms are "male" and "female" when describing a persons gender.

Comment: THANK YOU SOMEOME ELSE GAVED ME THE ANWSER SO I DIDNT HAVE TO TRY YOURS THANK YOU ANY WAY!! FOR YOUR TIME, THANK YOU AGAIN!